# How to check the css display value (block, inline, etc) for element in Firefox Web Developer tool?

Tags: firefox, firebug

I am quite sure that with the good old Firebug, it was shown in the Layout tab, together with the box-sizing property.

Is it possible to tell in the Web Developer too? There is a Box Model tab which is quite similar to the Layout tab of Firebug, but it does not show this information.

Btw: I thought the built-in Web Developer was built on Firebug, but when reading about it it actually seems that they are two quite separate things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature is currently only available in [Firefox Nightly](http://nightly.mozilla.org/).

Comment: So Nightly is sort of a beta, right? So this means, that eventally it will come with all versions of Firefox?

Comment: Yes, every 6 weeks the code moves on to the next level:
Nightly -> Aurora -> Beta -> Release